# Can't open photos in Google-earth

Tags: photos, graphics, google-earth

I have encountered this issue on **both different PCs** recently. When I click on Panoramio photos in Google-earth, only blank pop-up appears, as in the screenshot below:
[image]

I have already tried the following:

- Switch between OpenGL and DirectX graphic modes
- Cleared memory cache
- Cleared disk cache
- Disabled Atmosphere

Have someone encountered such abnormality?

Comment: Are you running it from the web ?  Panoramio is probly a plug-in, via the web that would make it a plug-in of a plug-in sort of, you could clear out the folder for the activex stuff on the computer , and try and DL it again?  https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?hideforumtitle=false&hl=en&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.panoramio.com%2Fforum%2Fview%2Fpanoramio-group-__root__&place=forum%2Fpanoramio-group-__root__&showpopout=true&showsearch=true&showtabs=false&urlimgupload=#!topic/panoramio-questions-support/IxTSjd2LU1o <-- here is a link to ask them, if you ask, it would be good to see the fixes

Comment: @Psycogeek Thank you for your comment, however I'm running the application installed on my PC.

Answer (score -2):

You were probably browsing in China, where panoramio.com is acting very unstable this few months. 99% of the time you cannot open it. I think the Chinese cable companies are cutting it off to save the network traffic.

Comment: Actually I didn't.

Comment: Welcome to SU. If you want to check facts about the question before answering, it's a good idea asking that question as a comment to the original question.