# Panormaio images loading  very slow in Google Earth

Tags: images, graphics, google-earth

When I try to open a Panoramio image in Google Earth it takes about 20 seconds to load.

Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've figured out this issue.
I unchecked the option `Automatically detect settings` in:

```
Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings
```

This worked for me.

**NOTE**: However I still have [another](https://superuser.com/q/416070/111772) issue on two other PCs where the won't open at all.